# Using an inline microphone remote on a Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headphones

I have a windows 10 laptop that supports a 4-pole headset, and I would like to use the button to control music like I am able to on my phone (Android) and have on a borrowed laptop (Mac Air). After searching any terms I can come up with, I'm stumped. The microphone on this headset works fine, but I cannot discover any way to control music or get any action out of pressing the remote/microphone button. Is there any known way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 headset standards, OMTP, AHJ and Apple.  While stereo audio is compatible with each other, it is known to mute the sound a little if you are mixing standards.  Unfortunately, the remote controls are not compatible with each other.  You need to find out which standard your headset and laptop conform to.  There are adapter from one standard to another, if you Google for them.